# How to get desired Date format?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

From database by using

```
 Convert(VARCHAR,WorkDATE, 106) AS WorkDate.
```

I am getting output as  03 Apr 2014.

I want the current date in the same format as database as returns in vb.net.

Comment: No, Like: 03 Apr 2014 @Soombinakundi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:- Dates should be stored in your database as `Date` types. There is no formatting associated with this.

You can then apply some formatting to the date in your code if you wish using the `Date.ToString(format)` overload

```
Dim dt As DataTable
'Populate your DataTable here "SELECT WorkDate FROM YourTable"
Dim d As Date = dt.Rows(0).Field(Of Date)("WorkDate")
Debug.WriteLine(d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

If you cannot change the data type in the database, or indeed the query, then you can parse a date of a specified format using the DateTime.ParseExact method:

```
Dim dt As DataTable
'Populate your DataTable here "SELECT WorkDate FROM YourTable"
Dim workDateString As String = dt.Rows(0).Field(Of String)("WorkDate")
Dim d As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(dr.item("Date"), "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following as you desired

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 120) 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h)
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 121) ' yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm
```

Comment: My database code is fixed.
I want in vb.net coding.